# TrueType Fonts in LaTeX document directory

Tags: fonts, pdftex, truetype

I am trying to create some templates for my institution, and by our corporate design guide, we are strongly encouraged to use a provided TrueType font.

Now, as I personally use lualatex, I have previously been able to use the `fontspec` package to use the provided TrueType fonts. To do so, I supplied a copy of the fonts with every template I wrote, such that it was available alongside the `*.cls` files I created.

However, not all of my colleagues use lualatex, so I need to come up with a way to make the classes (together with the fonts) available for pdflatex as well.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm) and [here](http://c.caignaert.free.fr/Install-ttf-Font.pdf) to generate files `myfont.map`, `myfont.fd`, `myfont.tfm` and put the into thei respective local directories

```
    /texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/myfont.map
    /texmf-local/fonts/tfm/MyFont/myfont.tfm
    /texmf-local/fonts/vf/MyFont/myfont.vf
```

then I do `texhash` to update cache and enable the map using

```
    updmap --sys --enable Map myfont.map
```

while in an exemplary latex document I used

```
    % file: example.tex
    \documentclass{article}

    \font\myfont=myfont

    \begin{document}
        This is regular text.
        \myfont This is text in different font.
    \end{document}
```

Compiling it with `pdflatex` this produced the intended output. However, I am looking for a way to have all the files placed inside my working directory, such that they go alongside `example.tex`, i.e., my directory structure should look similar t this:

```
    <working directory>
     |- example.tex
     |- fonts
        |- map/dvips/myfont.map
        |- tfm/MyFont/myfont.tfm
        |- vf/MyFont/myfont.vf
```

My intention is, that while compiling, the directory-local version is used, but without previously doing a `texhash` or `updmap`.

My system is Windows 11 + texlive. I would greatly appreciate any information about my desired setup, even for other OSes or MikTeX.

Also, feel free to suggest an alternative TrueType font setup, which works with pdflatex and lualatex.

Comment: maybe it is just in the example but you don't want to use `\font\myfont=myfont` in a real document otherwise `\myfont` won't be known to the latex font system so will not honour `\large` or `\bfseries` or any other variant, you should declare it via \DeclareFontFamily (you could look at times.sty and t1phv.fd for a simple example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True. For now, however, I am only focused on making the font paths work, afterwards I will focus on a robust implementation.

Comment: you can look in texmf.cnf for the paths so for tfm for example `TFMFONTS = $TEXMFDOTDIR;{$TEXMF/fonts,$VARTEXFONTS}/tfm//`  so I think they need to be in the current directory or in a local texmf tree under `fonts` (or set TEXMFFONTS and put them anywhere)

Comment: bu see % This variable exists only to be redefined; it is used in nearly all
% search paths. If a document has source files not only in the current
% directory but also in subdirectories, it is convenient to set
% TEXMFDOTDIR=.// so that everything will be searched automatically.
% On the other hand, if you never want the current directory to be
% searched at all, setting TEXMFDOTDIR=/nonesuch should come close.

Comment: "feel free to suggest an alternative TrueType font setup":  Unless the suggested font is very bizarre, search in TeX Font Cataloge for a similar default font in LaTeX distributions. No one will notice the differences.

Comment: Hi @Fran, that is not an option. The font is HelveticaNeueLtCom, and in the corporate design, "lookalike" is not sufficient. Thank you for your suggstion, though.